# Use firebase cloud function to send GET request to non-google server

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am setting up Firebase cloud functions to make API calls to a non-google service. For testing I am using [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) as the API. the response I am receiving is a 403 error.

I have looked at other problems [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415759/use-firebase-cloud-function-to-send-post-request-to-non-google-server) to this but the answer stated upgrading to a paid firebase account would fix the problem. Upon upgrading to the [blaze plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/?gclid=CjwKCAjwkenqBRBgEiwA-bZVtsEQF4rrJYhTcbKMBQj-YaughH1gvmU7F1HqVvm8PHnX2YrOaL0BzRoCdx4QAvD_BwE) I fixed the Firebase blocking outgoing http calls but I now am stuck at the 403 error being returned by any API I have tried making requests from.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});

export const getJson = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    cors( req, res, async ()=> {
        try {
            let info = await req.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
            res.send(info);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).send(`catch block hit: ${error}`);
        }
    })
})
```

I expected the API call to return a json object:

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```

what I am receiving back is:

```
 "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()"
```

NOTE: I can receive the expected result if I make the [get request](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1) from [postman](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/launching_postman/sending_the_first_request/)

Your help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch a URL with Google Cloud functions? request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275148/how-to-fetch-a-url-with-google-cloud-functions-request)

Comment: See also some similar answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56410014/how-to-make-get-request-firebase-cloud-functions/56414318#56414318 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867732/how-to-grab-json-file-from-external-urlplaces-api-using-firebase-functions/56872063#56872063

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req` is the request sent to the server, and `req.get()` is used to get the headers of that request. If you want to *make* a request, you need to fire off your own. You can do that with raw node (eg, `https` package) or bring in a package like `axios` or `isomorphic-fetch`. Something like this:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const axios = require('axios')
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

export const getJson = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  cors( req, res, async ()=> {
    try {
      let info = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
      res.send(info.data);
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(`catch block hit: ${error}`);
    }
  })
})
```